# EF connection String Error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, web-config

My connection String in *web.config* file:

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="DefaultConnection" 
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
        connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-EFcodefirst-20131213155231;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-EFcodefirst-20131213155231.mdf" />
</connectionStrings>
```

My context File

```
namespace EFcodefirst.Models
{
    public class SampleContext: DbContext
    {    
        public DbSet<EFcodefirst.Models.Customer> Customers { get; set; }        
    }
}
```

My controller

```
SampleContext dbContext = new SampleContext();
var customerList = dbContext.Customers.ToList();
return View(customerList);
```

Here is the error

> An error occurred while getting provider information from the database. This can be caused by Entity Framework using an incorrect connection string. Check the inner exceptions for details and ensure that the connection string is correct.

Please help me to solve this problem

Comment: Connection string seem to be Ok..can you add your context file

Comment: sure nilesh , thanks very much, i edit the question, please have a look

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are trying to create database in same file which is used by ASP.NET membership and you don't have SQLEXPRESS installed on your machine (otherwise Entity Framework would create database with `YourNamespace.SampleContext` name in your SQLEXPRESS database). So, just add another connection string which will point to another database file:

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="SampleContext"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
        connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=Sample;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\Sample.mdf" />
   <add name="DefaultConnection" 
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
        connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-EFcodefirst-20131213155231;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-EFcodefirst-20131213155231.mdf" />
</connectionStrings>
```

NOTE: If you don't want connection string to have same name as your context class, you can provide connection string name to constructor of base context class:

```
public class SampleContext: DbContext
{    
    public SampleContext()
       : base("AnotherConnectionStringName")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<EFcodefirst.Models.Customer> Customers { get; set; }        
}
```

Comment: invalid ":" token that is used in between samplecontext and base("DefaultContext")

Comment: @Jat.net sorry, forgot the braces

Comment: its ok, which braces please

Comment: @Jat.net do you have SQLEXPRESS installed on your machine?

Comment: I have installled sqlserver 2008 management studio installed sir @sergey

Comment: @Jat.net management studio is just tool to connect to database, it is not a database server. See my updated answer

Comment: @Jat.net please, don't call people *sir* :) And yes, you have to, because you can't reuse existing asp.net database with your context

Comment: Ok, i think its better if we chat and start with this problm, u please start our chat room(as i dnt know how to start ).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43234/discussion-between-sergey-berezovskiy-and-jat-net)

Answer (score -1):

Modify your dbcontext file :

```
public class SampleContext: DbContext
{    
    public SampleContext()
       : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<EFcodefirst.Models.Customer> Customers { get; set; }        
}
```

Comment: -1 you copy-pasted my answer and even forgot to add braces for constructor, as I did

Comment: Actually i was writing the answer but before i finished you already posted that so..i prefer to copy your answer :D

Comment: Please confirm which braces are to removed ? @SergeyBerezovskiy

Comment: @Nilesh copy-pasting existing answers is not very good idea) Why create exactly same answer as one already provided?

Comment: Sorry really, bt i m not getting the point, please clear ur views

Comment: @Jat.net SampleContext `()` :base("DefaultConnection")
    {

Comment: I correct , but the same problem exist :(

An error occurred while getting provider information from the database. This can be caused by Entity Framework using an incorrect connection string. Check the inner exceptions for details and ensure that the connection string is correct.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy i was passive answering this question.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy u there